# Drawing of a random sample of X observations

Tags: r

I am currently working on the `Boston` data. So I downloaded the library(MASS) data(Boston). As I found on numerous websites there is a famous assignment on this based on this regression model (OLS) `medv = β0 + b1crim + b2chas + ε`. I now want to draw a random sample of `X` observations e.g. 30 and save the subsample as object `ZZ`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
ZZ <- Boston |> sample_n(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```r
data("Boston", package = "MASS")
keep_rows <- sample(nrow(Boston), size = 30, replace = FALSE)
ZZ <- Boston[keep_rows, ]
```